# POSTMAN - Modifying response for GET request to JSON format prior to subsequent POST request - ALMOST COMPLETED - SEE EDIT

Tags: json, get, postman

**QUICK SUMMARY:** Want to make a GET request in which the response body is converted to the standard JSON format so that I can point to those very JSON objects when setting environment variables and these environment variables will be referenced in a subsequent POST.

**DETAILED BACKGROUND:** Working on various collections that iterate through a list of of WIRELESS ACCESS POINTS (AP) from an excel sheet. This particular collection has ONE GET and ONE subsequent POST for each AP in the excel list: it's purpose is to send GET request to ARUBA CENTRAL API to get the configuration (10 attributes) of a specific AP based on the SERIAL# value from excel. Then to send back a POST request with 11 attributes to reconfigure the AP:

1. Seven attributes remaining the same and therefore referenced from the initial GET responsebody
2. Two attributes changing, their values being taken from the excel sheet (easy)
3. two attributes being static (easy)

Then it moves on to the next serial # in the excel for the next set of get/post requests and so on.

**PROBLEM SUMMARY:** ONLY having issue with #1 of POST: I have been using this sort of methodology for many different API calls for ARUBA CENTRAL with much success. However, the particular API call in this case returns a response body that is NOT in the typical JSON format I am used to dealing with, as you will see below:

**GET :**

```
{{base_url}}/configuration/v1/ap_settings_cli/{{SERIAL}}
```

->This sends a GET to the API of Aruba Central with the value of SERIAL taken from the excel sheet.

**RESPONSE BODY**

```
[
  "per-ap-settings ab:xz:1x:5y:3c:65",
  "  hostname room-1-ap",
  "  ip-address 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 \"\"",
  "  wifi0-mode access",
  "  wifi1-mode access",
  "  g-channel 0 -127",
  "  a-channel 0 -127",
  "  a-external-antenna 0",
  "  g-external-antenna 0",
  "  zonename _#ALL#_"
]
```

-> Response Headers -> Content-Type: application/json , but this is not the typical JSON format I am used to dealing with. Need it in the typical JSON format so that the TESTS section works

My thoughts are to modify the response body to the following standard JSON format:

**SUGGESTED MODIFICATION to RESPONSE BODY**

```
{
  "per-ap-settings": "ab:xz:1x:5y:3c:65",
  "hostname": "room-1-ap",
  "ip-address": "0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 \"\"",
  "wifi0-mode": "access",
  "wifi1-mode": "access",
  "g-channel": "0 -127",
  "a-channel": "0 -127",
  "a-external-antenna": "0",
  "g-external-antenna": "0",
  "zonename": "_#ALL#_"
}
```

If I can get them in that format, I believe the the following lines of code will work:

**CURRENT TESTS (under GET REQUEST)**

```
pm.environment.set("per-ap-settings", pm.response.json().per-ap-settings);
pm.environment.set("hostname", pm.response.json.hostname);
pm.environment.set("ip-address", pm.response.json().ip-address);
pm.environment.set("wifi0-mode", pm.response.json().wifi0-mode);
pm.environment.set("wifi1-mode", pm.response.json().wifi1-mode);
pm.environment.set("g-channel", pm.response.json().g-channel);
pm.environment.set("a-channel", pm.response.json().a-channel);
```

The following is the subsequent POST which is failing because the environment variables are not being set (from the GET) and they are not being set because my responsebody is not in the typical JSON format.

Note the 7 environment variables referenced. Also note that AGAIN and GGAIN are variables that are retrieved from the values under the excel sheet's AGAIN and GGAIN headers. Finally note that zoneA and newsite are static values. To reiterate, the only issue with the POST is that the values for the 7 environment variables are not being set and instead show as NULL:

**POST REQUEST (which reference environment variables from previous GET)**

```
{
  "clis": [
  "per-ap-settings {{per-ap-settings}}",
  "  hostname {{hostname}}",
  "  ip-address {{ip-address}}",
  "  wifi0-mode {{wifi0-mode}}",
  "  wifi1-mode {{wifi1-mode}}",
  "  g-channel {{g-channel}}",
  "  a-channel {{a-channel}}",
  "  a-external-antenna {{AGAIN}}",
  "  g-external-antenna {{GGAIN}}",
  "  zonename zoneA",
  "  rf-zone newsite"
  ]
}
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**
Multiple failed javascript templates generated using my company's version of chatgpt to convert the responsebody from the GET request to the correct JSON format (so that I can reference the environment variables appropriately). I inserted these templates in TESTS within my GET REQUEST. For the moment, I removed setting environment variables so I can focus on the javascript template and look at my console log where I am logging the new output. However, the best I get is the following:

**CONSOLE OUTPUT (for conversion to right JSON format):**

```
{per-ap-settings: "ab:xz:1x:5y:3c:65", "": " zonename _#ALL#_"}
per-ap-settings: "ab:xz:1x:5y:3c:65"
"": " zonename _#ALL#_"
```

**MAJOR EDIT!!**

My new Chatgpt-generated CODE has gotten me 99% where I need to be. I just need help with:

1. I don't want to remove the following 4 characters that appear at the end of the line that has the words "ip-address":

   ""
2. I need to make sure that the syntac for my pm.environment.set lines are correct. I don't think they are right now.

**NEW CODE (under TEST under GET REQUEST):**

```
// Get the response body as a JSON object
responseBody = pm.response.json();

// Initialize an empty object to store the JSON format
const jsonFormat = {};

// Iterate through each line in the response body array
responseBody.forEach(line => {
  // Remove extra spaces and split the line by space to get the key-value pair
  // Exclude escaped quotes from being split
  const [key, ...valueParts] = line.trim().split(/(?<!\\) /);

  // Join the value parts back together and add the key-value pair to the jsonFormat object
  jsonFormat[key] = valueParts.join(' ');
});

// Log the jsonFormat object to the console
console.log(jsonFormat);
console.log(jsonFormat["per-ap-settings"])
console.log(jsonFormat.hostname);
console.log(jsonFormat["ip-address"])
console.log(jsonFormat["wifi0-mode"])
console.log(jsonFormat["wifi1-mode"])
console.log(jsonFormat["g-channel"])
console.log(jsonFormat["g-channel"])

// If you want to set the converted JSON as an environment variable, uncomment the following line:
// pm.environment.set("convertedJson", JSON.stringify(jsonFormat));


pm.environment.set("hostname", pm.response.json().hostname);
pm.environment.set("per-ap-settings", pm.response.json["per-ap-settings"]);
pm.environment.set("ip-address", pm.response.json["ip-address"]);
pm.environment.set("wifi0-mode", pm.response.json["wifi0-mode"]);
pm.environment.set("wifi1-mode", pm.response.json["wifi1-mode"]);
pm.environment.set("g-channel", pm.response.json["g-channel"]);
pm.environment.set("a-channel", pm.response.json["a-channel"]);
```

Here is the new CONSOLE LOG -> Notice the missing two \ in the "ip-address" line

```
{per-ap-settings: "dc:b7:ac:cd:e1:7e", hostname: "fw-cp-125-eorwdw-ap", ip-address: "0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 """…}
per-ap-settings: "dc:b7:ac:cd:e1:7e"
hostname: "fw-cp-125-eorwdw-ap"
ip-address: "0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 """
wifi0-mode: "access"
wifi1-mode: "access"
g-channel: "0 -127"
a-channel: "0 -127"
a-external-antenna: "0"
g-external-antenna: "0"
zonename: "_#ALL#_"
 
"dc:b7:ac:cd:e1:7e
 
"fw-cp-125-eorwdw-ap"
 
"0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 """
 
"access"
 
"access"
 
"0 -127"
 
"0 -127"
```

Answer (score 0):

The console log will not show the escape characters when you log a string.  They are there though.

For example...

```
const response = pm.response.json();

let newObj = {}

response.forEach(element => {
    let split = element.trim().split(/(?<=^\S+)\s/);
    newObj[split[0]] = split[1]
})

console.log(newObj);
pm.environment.set("object",JSON.stringify(newObj))
```

Returns the same as what you have in the console logs.

[image]

If I then use that environment variable to drive the next request against Postman Echo.

[image]

You can see that the escape characters do still exist.

[image]